# jQuery get image map parent image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image map for all my images and when I click a map area I want to update the class of the parent image that is linked to the image map. I have tried `closest()` and `parent()`

```
<div class="preview iphone">
  <div class="phone-screen">
    <img id="mail-1" src="img/mail-1.png" class="active" usemap="#Map">
    <map name="Map" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2016-06-09-203440">
        <area  data-img="mail-2" href="#" shape="rect" coords="105,365,172,415" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
    </map>
    <img id="mail-2" src="img/mail-2.png" class="hidden">
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("area").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var link = $(this).attr("data-img");
            $('#'+link).toggleClass( "active hidden" );


            $(this).parent('img').toggleClass( "active hidden" );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use `$(this).parent('map#ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2016-06-09-203440').next('#mail-2').toggleClass("active hidden");`

Comment: I will have multiple images and maps so I won't be able to hardcode the id's

Comment: it is still ok `$(this).parent('map').next('img')‌​.toggleClass("active hidden");` assuming that the target img is always next to the map

Comment: sorry, this incorrectly updates the image under the `map` and not the image above which is the one that is linked to the `map`

Comment: which image are you targeting?the one next to map or before?just use next() or prev() depending on the image